# OpenERP: How to invoke a function every time the user deletes an item from a tree

Tags: odoo

According to this forum [Functional Fields](http://forum.openerp.com/forum/topic30402.html):

> "functional fields are called while when a create,write or any other
>   orm method called"

I have tested the idea, I created a function field and it is being invoked every time I
(1) add a new item on the list/tree OR
(2) edit an existing item on the list/tree

but I would like to know if there is way to call/invoke a functional field whenever the user deletes an item from a tree?

```
class payment(osv.osv):

    def _get_total_check_info(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context=None):
        """
        _get_total_check_info() :
        Function that automatically computes for the Total Check Info upon saving
        """
        result={}
        check_amount = 0
        for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            for n in record.check_info_ids:
                res = self.pool.get('cashier.check.information').browse(cr, uid, n.id)
                if res:
                    check_amount +=  res['check_amount']
                    print "check_amount", res['check_amount']
                    print "check_amount Total", check_amount

        result[record.id] = check_amount
        return result

        _name = 'payment'
        _description = __doc__

        _columns = {
       'check_info_ids': fields.one2many('check.information', 'pymt_id', 'Check Information'),
       'total_check_amount': fields.function(_get_total_check_info, method=True, type='float', string='Total Check Amount', store=True),
        }
payment()


class check_information(osv.osv):

    def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        """
        unlink():
        Function used to override the unlink method
        """
        #Your code goes here.
        print "here at unlink function"
        return super(check_information, self).unlink(cr, uid, ids, context=context)

    _name = 'check.information'
    _description = __doc__

    _columns = {
        'pymt_id': fields.many2one('payment', 'Payment ID'),
        'check_date': fields.date('Check Date'),
        'check_number': fields.char('Check Number', size=50),
        'check_amount': fields.float('Check Amount', digits=(16, 2)),
        'payee': fields.char('Payee', size=100),
        'bank': fields.char('Bank', size=20),
        'bank_branch': fields.char('Bank Branch', size=20),
    }
check_information()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via object you can call your functional field's method by creating object

```
def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    unlink():
    Function used to override the unlink method
    """
    #Your code goes here.
    lst_ids = []
    for brw_rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        print "here at unlink function"
        lst_ids.append(brw_rec.pymt_id.id)
    self.pool.get('payment')._get_total_check_info(cr, uid, lst_ids, 'total_check_amount', None, context=context)
    return super(check_information, self).unlink(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

Comment: Hi Arya, I'm getting a "NameError: global name 'total_check_amount' is not defined" error. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: check out the ans. Whenever we explicitly invoke any functional field, we have to pass the field name as a string. In your case 'total_check_amount' is your field name.

Comment: Still getting this error - KeyError: "Field '0' does not exist in object 'browse_record(payment, 3)'"

Comment: @codemickeycode Most welcome. If you got what you wanted then you should accept the answer to complete the flow.

Comment: Arya, I have a follow-up question though. I am able to get the desired 'total_check_amount' value via print statement inside the _get_total_check_info() function but I am unable to display it on the actual 'total_check_amount' field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that true the `fields.functions` is called only when we try to update or create record. but If you want to do what you wan then, form over-ride `unlink` method` then form self_. columns find your field and get function name and then call methods. By doing this you will simulate the exact behavior done by ORM on crate or write.

```
class test(osv.osv):
    .
    .
    .
    def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        #Your code goes here.
        return super(test, self).unlink(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

Thank you

Comment: @ firebug - thanks for the confirmation. Can you give me an example how to override the unlink method?

Comment: Hi firebug! Im not sure I know how to apply the example you've given. I have updated my code above to illustrate a one2many and many2one relationship between payment class' check_info_ids and check_information class' pymt_id.

I've placed the unlink/override method in check_information class. It's working everytime I try to delete an item from the check_information tree but I cant figure out how to call  the _get_total_check_info method under payment class.

Thanks man and so sorry to bug you with this